# How do you run a script on login in *nix?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, unix, shell

I know I once know how to do this but... how do you run a script (bash is OK) on login in unix?

Comment: What login? UI login? like gnome, GTK, Unity? Perhaps a new shell login from the tty? What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

From [wikipedia Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)

> When Bash starts, it executes the commands in a variety of different
>   scripts.
>
> When Bash is invoked as an interactive
>   login shell, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file
>   /etc/profile, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for
>   ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and
>   ~/.profile, in that order, and reads
>   and executes commands from the first
>   one that exists and is readable.
>
> When a login shell exits, Bash reads
>   and executes commands from the file
>   ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
>
> When an interactive shell that is not
>   a login shell is started, Bash reads
>   and executes commands from ~/.bashrc,
>   if that file exists. This may be
>   inhibited by using the --norc option.
>   The --rcfile file option will force
>   Bash to read and execute commands from
>   file instead of ~/.bashrc.

Comment: only a decade late, but: what if that command requires sudo (e.g. mounting a network share from a NAS into the user's home dir)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans excellent question, maybe the Sudo is assumed since it's in the system' files?

Comment: maybe, but maybe not - hopefully someone can still answer that for us =(

Comment: `sudo` is an optional add-on, nothing much will run it unless you specifically (install it and) ask for it. If your command requires noninterctive `sudo` privileges, check the `sudo` documentation for how to set that up.

Answer (score 30):

At login, most shells execute a login script, which you can use to execute your custom script.  The login script the shell executes depends, of course, upon the shell:

- bash:  .bash_profile, .bash_login, .profile (for backwards compabitibility)
- sh: .profile
- tcsh and csh: .login
- zsh: .zshrc

You can probably find out what shell you're using by doing

```
echo $SHELL
```

from the prompt.

For a slightly wider definition of 'login', it's useful to know that on most distros when X is launched, your .xsessionrc will be executed when your X session is started.

Comment: echo $0 should reveal which shell is being used, although occasionally I've seen 'sh' reported, when it's really 'ksh' - on HP-UX or Solaris I think.

Answer (score 10):

When using Bash, the first of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile` will be run for an interactive login shell. I believe `~/.profile` is generally run by Unix shells besides Bash. Bash will run `~/.bashrc` for a non-login interactive shell.

I typically put everything I want to always set in `.bashrc` and then run it from `.bash_profile`, where I also set up a few things that should run only when I'm logging in, such as setting up `ssh-agent` or running `screen`.

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to run *one* script and *only* one script, you can make it that users default shell.

```
echo "/usr/bin/uptime" >> /etc/shells
vim /etc/passwd  
  * username:x:uid:grp:message:homedir:/usr/bin/uptime
```

can have interesting effects :)  ( its not secure tho, so don't trust it too much. nothing like setting your default shell to be a script that wipes your drive. ... although, .. I can imagine a scenario where that could be amazingly useful )

Answer (score 3):

Place it in your [bash profile](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/stable/postlfs/profile.html):

```
~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are on OSX, then it's `~/.profile`

Comment: This is not entirely correct. `.profile` is run by interactive Bourne shell instances, regardless of OS; but if yours is not a run of the mill Bourne shell, maybe it won't. Bash out of the box will look for `.bash_profile` and if it is not found fall back to `.profile`. A common arrangement if you do have `.bash_profile` is to include an instruction to _also_ load `.profile` if present. These days, MacOS out of the box defaults to Zsh, not Bash, which has still different logic.

Answer (score 3):

`Launchd` is a the preferred way in OS X.

If you want it to run on your login put it in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Start `launchd` item

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.bob.plist
```

Stop item

```
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.bob.plist
```

Example `com.bob.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.bob</string>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>/usr/bin/java</string>
<string>-jar</string>
<string>/Users/user/program.jar</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was frustrated with this problem for days. Nothing worked on ubuntu. If I put the call in /etc/profile it all crashed at login attempt. I couldn't use "Startup Applications" as that was not what I wanted. That only sets the script for that current user.

Finally I found this little article: http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-0.5.html

The solution would be:

1. find out the $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS path:

   echo $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
2. put your script in that directory

Answer (score 2):

Add an entry in `/etc/profile` that executes the script.  This will be run during every log-on.  If you are only doing this for your own account, use one of your login scripts (e.g. `.bash_profile`) to run it.

Answer (score 2):

Search your local system's bash man page for ^INVOCATION for information on which file is going to be read at startup.

```
man bash
/^INVOCATION
```

Also in the FILES section,

```
   ~/.bash_profile
          The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
   ~/.bashrc
          The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
```

Add your script to the proper file. Make sure the script is in the $PATH, or use the absolute path to the script file.

Answer (score 1):

The script `~/.bash_profile` is run on login.