# Store frequently used commands in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I use some Linux commands more frequently like going to a specific directory, grep for some text etc. I assigned a variable for each command and kept them in a script file and I run the script file every time when I login to my Linux box so that I can use the variables instead of typing lengthy commands.

Is it possible that I can make sure that my script file runs everytime when I login to my Linux box so that I need not run it everytime?

Is there an alternate way of storing my frequently used commands so that they will be available when I open my Linux box?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you run a script on login in \*nix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97137/how-do-you-run-a-script-on-login-in-nix)

Comment: If the commands are frequently used, chances are those would be in the shell history.  Press `Ctrl-R` and start typing out a few characters of the command you want to execute.  This would bring up the last command including the specified character(s).  Pressing `Ctrl-R` again brings up the next anterior command.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bash (probably are), add it to your `.bashrc`. You will find it in your home directory.

Other shells have corresponding startup scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Adding commands to .bashrc for a non-login shell, or to .bash_profile for login shells (assuming, of course, that you're using bash).

From the [bash manual entry](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login,
>   and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from
>   the first one that exists and is readable. The --noprofile option may
>   be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the
>   file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
>   reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists. This
>   may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option
>   will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of
>   ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your script into your `.bashrc` file, it is in your home directory

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

It only works when you are using bash.

Answer (score 0):

What is about alias?

You can store them in the ~/.bashrc, when I am right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.bashrc` file but this script is executed when you open an interactive Bash shell. That is every time you connect to a server with a terminal (if Bash is your default shell) or open another shell that opens an interactive shell (like `su - $USER`).

If you work locally with X-Window GUI on Linux (Unix) the script will be executed every time you open a terminal program (like *Konsole* in KDE or  *gnome-terminal*). It maybe not what you expected. In this case you can hack a [.xinit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc) script or use your display manager or desktop environment way to execute a script upon start. It is hard to tell how because it is  specific to your environment (Linux/ Unix distribution or desktop environment (KDE, GNOME, ...) ) .