# Automatically open terminal when running bash script

Tags: linux, redhat

To get the script to run in terminal, I have to select the option to open in terminal and write `sh script name.sh`Is there a way I can reduce that to a single step, i.e. a launcher that automatically opens the script in a terminal after logging as a root ? I've tried to look it up on Google, but I haven't found any useful advice (perhaps I'm not executing the search properly).

Comment: you mean running the script as start up script.

Comment: I mean to run it after logging in

Comment: Yep, that's it. See my answer below.

Comment: Is that ok with bash ??

Comment: see my edited answer and yes it's ok for bash.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is running your script as start up script. In that case place the script you want to run in the `/etc/init.d` directory and make the script executable with command `chmod 755 scriptname.sh`.

See the below related threads for more information

https://askubuntu.com/questions/290099/how-to-run-a-script-during-boot-as-root

[How to run a shell script at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup)

**EDIT:**

if you want to run your script after your login is successful then you need to place your script in `~/.bash_profile`. See this related post

[How do you run a script on login in *nix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97137/how-do-you-run-a-script-on-login-in-nix)

Comment: I mean include your script path there (OR) call your script from `bash_profile`

Comment: `bash_profile` itself is a script. So you just need to call your script from there like `/bin/bash /path/scriptname.sh`.

Comment: @user3476633, if this answer helped you then try accepting it as answer.

Comment: I know you did your best but nothing happened when editing the bash profile ... I edit it by "nano ~/.bash_profile and nothing happen

Comment: What did you added in the file. show the excerpt from bash_profile.

Comment: I added "/root/script.sh" at the beginning of the file

Comment: I mean post the entry of bash_profile. Edit your question and post it.